# Sending item from list webpart to infopath webpart

Tags: 2013, list, infopath, web-part-connection

So on a page, I have 2 web parts.

- A list which contains some items.
- And a InfoPath web part.

I would like to send the items from the list to the Infopath viewer but I don't know how to achieve this.

Right now I'm trying to use "`Connections`" option. So from the list I tried using the "`Send Row of Data To`" and then I selected "`content type`".

I'm not sure what else I could select for provider name. And I left blank the other box. I tried several different combinations but I don't know how or if it is possible to do.

When I tried that a select column appeared on my list. But if I press it nothing happens. My Infopath web part does not show item info just blank everywhere. Am I doing something wrong?

## EDIT

Oh wow i got it to work with one single field. Is this how it works? You can select one single field and that's all? I mean how useless this is xD I can't understand SharePoint philosphy. Am i doing wrong or it's the way we use this thing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few changes to the infopath form to be able to load all the fields when you select a single item from the list.

- Click Data connections -> Add -> Recieve Data -> SharePoint List ->
  enter site URL -> Select List -> Select all the fields you would
  want to use in the form -> Finish.
- Create a New View to use in the WebPart Page.
- Add all the fields you wish to display in the view
- I would add ID field to the view (as it is unique for all items), to populate the other fields
- On ID Field, click on Add Rules.
- Action Rule -> Query Data connection (the one which we just created)
- Action Rule -> Set Fields Value (select the field from main connection). In the Value -> select the same field from Second connection, and filter data where ID (from main connection) equals ID (from second connection)
  Repeat the same for all the fields.

Now in the WebPart page, use the ID field to provide data from the list to InfoPath form. 
 - When you select an item in the list, data is sent to the Infopath form and ID field is populated.
 - As soon, ID field is updated, all the remaining fields will be populated as per the rules we set in the form.

Hope this helps.